# SQL - Why values not selected?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

*Table have values:*

name

```
УСЛУГИ ВЕТЕРИНАРНОЙ ПОМОЩИ КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ СТОМАТОЛОГА
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА БЕСПЛАТНАЯ
УСЛУГИ СТОМАТОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ ХИРУРГ-СТОМАТОЛОГ
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА-ХИРУРГА
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА-ХИРУРГА
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА
КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА ДЕТСКОГО БЕСПЛАТНАЯ ВСЕ ВИДЫ
```

*If i make query*

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
name LIKE '%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь$-()/]'
OR name LIKE '%-СТОМАТОЛОГ%'
```

*I get result:*

```
    УСЛУГИ ВЕТЕРИНАРНОЙ ПОМОЩИ КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ СТОМАТОЛОГА
    КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА БЕСПЛАТНАЯ
    УСЛУГИ СТОМАТОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ ХИРУРГ-СТОМАТОЛОГ
    КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА-ХИРУРГА
    КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА
    КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА-ХИРУРГА
    КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА
    КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ (ПРИЕМ) ВРАЧА-СТОМАТОЛОГА ДЕТСКОГО БЕСПЛАТНАЯ ВСЕ ВИДЫ
```

*But if i make query:*

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
name LIKE '%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь$-()/]'
```

i get result: `УСЛУГИ ВЕТЕРИНАРНОЙ ПОМОЩИ КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ СТОМАТОЛОГА`

As i see `%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь$-()/]` should include `%-СТОМАТОЛОГ%` but it not worked.

*Tell me please why in second query i get only one value in result?*

Really use only `%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь$-()/]` or filter `%[$-()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь$-()/]` not work for filter `%-СТОМАТОЛОГ%` ?

P.S.: i dont understand why in first query we get 8 rows in result and in second query we get only one row in result.

Comment: Can you please change the result to english characters or faciliate it in a reasonable manner? Cause I'm getting head aches in attempting to read Greek. :)

Comment: @FabianBigler it's Russian

Comment: @AndreyChernukha See. I dont even grasp the right language. :)

Comment: Your string literals should be prefixed with `N`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand all data in utf-8

Comment: What collation are you using to get UTF-8 support in SQL Server? The data is Unicode, correct? If so, always use the `N` prefix for string literals. Compare: `SELECT 'стоматолог', N'стоматолог';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LIKE` clause should be:

```
LIKE N'%[-$()/ ]стоматолог[аеёиоуыэюяъь$-()/]'
```

with `-` at the first position or otherwise it treats it as defining range between `$` and `(`. Also, add `N` to make it search Unicode characters.

Comment: +1 for **with `-` at the first position or otherwise it treats it as defining range between `$` and `(`** tell me please where i can write about it rules?